# Compare accuracy of RF model in python

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I would like to calculate its accuracy (over the testing dataset).
The model has the following predicting values:

```
[0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

How can I compare it to actual values (in this case B or M) to get its accuracy over the testing data. This should be generic to other datasets values as well.
Here is the code I use for RandomForest model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load scikit's random forest classifier library
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
file_path = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data'
dataset2 = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=',')

train, test = train_test_split(dataset2, test_size=0.1)
y = pd.factorize(train[1])[0]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
features = train.columns[2:]
clf.fit(train[features], y)

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=2, oob_score=False, random_state=0,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)
# Apply the Classifier we trained to the test data 
clf.predict(test[features])
```

Comment: Are the following answers what you want to do? The meaning of the question was interpreted as wanting to evaluate accuracy with B, M of the original label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode B and M using sklearn's `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` as follows and return it with `inverse_transform()`. In addition, accuracy evaluation can be done using `ConfusionMatrix()` of `pandas_ml` package and sklearn's `accuracy_score()`.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load scikit's random forest classifier library
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
file_path = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data'
dataset2 = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=',')

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# Encode B, M to 0, 1
y = le.fit_transform(dataset2[1])
dataset2[1] = y

train, test = train_test_split(dataset2, test_size=0.1)
y = train[1]
y_test = test[1]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
features = train.columns[2:]
clf.fit(train[features], y)

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=2, oob_score=False, random_state=0,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)
# Apply the Classifier we trained to the test data
y_pred = clf.predict(test[features])

# Decode from 0, 1 to B, M
y_test_label = le.inverse_transform(y_test)
y_pred_label = le.inverse_transform(y_pred)

from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
confusion_matrix = ConfusionMatrix(y_test_label, y_pred_label)
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % confusion_matrix)
# Confusion matrix:
# Predicted   B   M  __all__
# Actual                    
# B          35   1       36
# M           4  17       21
# __all__    39  18       57

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test_label, y_pred_label)
# Out[14]: 0.035087719298245612
```

Note that `pandas_ml` can be easily installed by pip as shown below.

```python
pip install pandas_ml
```